# How do you keep clothes clean during action sequences?

Tags: filming

Not sure if this is the right StackExchange for this, but I don't see a more general film making SE so here goes...

I'm acting in a short spy film, and in two separate scenes I'm going to be hitting the ground in a suit.

We already shot the final shootout scene, but might need to do a reshoot.

The problem is, the sets aren't very clean. One is a restaurant and the other is a parking garage... during the shootout I ended up with dust and "something" all over my suit.

So, the question is... how can I keep that from happening so I'll look consistent between different takes? (And so my suit doesn't get stained...)

I tried putting down some a large clear plastic bag the other day, but it was too visible on camera...